# KVM - Windows guest cannot access host, but can ping both directions

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, kvm

I have a host running Fedora 36, guest is Win11
I am attempting to share a directory on the host box with a windows 11 guest.

Through research I found that samba is the generally recommended way to accomplish this share.

I have tried creating a virtual network, and connecting to that network In the vm settings
[image]

I also tried setting up bridge networking directly to the virb2 host interface.

In both cases I can ping the host from the guest and host to guest. And, I have internet access on the guest.

When I attempt to setup a network drive on the guest, I get "Windows cannot access [server ip][samba shared directory]"
[image]

Any suggestions? Is there something else I need to do within Windows (I know very little about Windows)?
TIA

**Additional Info**
`tcpdump -i virbr2 -n \(tcp port 139\)` returns
12:25:53.866275 IP 192.168.100.189.49908 > 192.168.100.1.netbios-ssn: Flags [S], seq 3481992815, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0

`iptables -nvL INPUT` returns:
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)                                                                               │
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                                              │
15895 6287K LIBVIRT_INP  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

**Firewall Commands I ran to fix the issue**

```
firewall-cmd --zone=libvirt --permanent --add-service=samba
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: That sounds a lot like a firewall problem (allowing pings but not access to Samba). You can run `tcpdump -i vibr2 -n \(tcp port 139\) or \( tcp port 445 \)` on the host in order to check that the Samba connections are received but not answered. What is the output of `iptables -nvL INPUT` / `nft list ruleset`?

Comment: Could also be poorly configured samba - without seeing samba config there's no way to be sure

Comment: You are throwing the word 'guest' about a lot, now this could just be what you call it, rather than 'server' and 'client', but if you are trying to connect from Windows 11 as a 'Guest' (no username & password), check if guest access is turned on, it is probably off by default.

Comment: @HaukeLaging I added the tcpdump output.

Comment: @RowlandPenny I am using the KVM terminology for clarity, indicating that this is a virtual machine trying to reach the host via SAMBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The host firewall kills the connection. So you have to explicitly allow the connection (either in the libvirt configuration or in the regular firewall configuration).

Comment: This answer sent me in the right direction. I added the commands I had to run to the question, in order to possibly help others